# What's wrong with my query?SQL with multiple update case

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update "money" with different value for different names.

```
select names,money from workers ;
```

Returns:

```
NAMES|MONEY
Frank|1250$
Tony|1240$
```

```
UPDATE workers
SET money = CASE 'names' WHEN 'Tony' THEN '1500$'
                         WHEN 'Frank' THEN '1600$' END
WHERE 'names' IN ('Tony','Frank');
```

The syntax is ok, but no rows were updated, why?

Comment: `'names'`.  Don't enclose identifiers in single quotes.

Comment: Please add as answer, so I can close question and give you feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column name shouldn't be enclosed into single quotes.

```
SQL> create table workers as
  2    select 'Frank' names, 0 money from dual union all
  3    select 'Tony', 0 from dual union all
  4    select 'Little', 0 from dual;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> update workers set
  2    money = case when names = 'Tony' then 1500
  3                 when names = 'Frank' then 1600
  4            end
  5  where names in ('Tony', 'Frank');

2 rows updated.

SQL> select * From workers;

NAMES       MONEY
------ ----------
Frank        1600
Tony         1500
Little          0

SQL>
```